# marquee equivalent in Nativescript mobile app development

Tags: html, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, marquee, nativescript-telerik-ui

I would like to know if there is **marquee** equivalent in **nativescript** likewise in HTML. I am working on a nativescript angular project and tried applying css definitions but it doesnt affect the text.

Appreciate any help on this.